# Selecting certain rows from a set of data files in Python

Tags: python, file, numpy, import

I am trying to manipulate some data with Python, but having quite a bit of difficulty (given that I'm still a rookie). I have taken some code from other questions/sites but still can't quite get what I want.

Basically what I need is to take a set of data files and select the data from 1 particular row of each of those files, then put it into a new file so I can plot it.

So, to get the data into Python in the first place I'm trying to use:

```
data = []
path = C:/path/to/file
for files in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, ‘*.*’)):
  data.append(list(numpy.loadtxt(files, skiprows=34))) #first 34 rows aren't used
```

This has worked great for me once before, but for some reason it won't work now. Any possible reasons why that might be the case?

Anyway, carrying on, this should give me a 2D list containing all the data.

Next I want to select a certain row from each data set, and can do so using:

```
x = list(xrange(30)) #since there are 30 files
```

Then:

```
rowdata = list(data[i][some particular row] for i in x)
```

Which gives me a list containing the value for that particular row from each imported file. This part seems to work quite nicely.

Lastly, I want to write this to a file. I have been trying:

```
f = open('path/to/file', 'w')
   for item in rowdata:
      f.write(item)
f.close()
```

But I keep getting an error. Is there another method of approach here?

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using numpy to load the text, you can use it to manipulate it as well.

```
import numpy as np
path = 'C:/path/to/file'
mydata = np.array([np.loadtxt(f) for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.*'))])
```

This will load all your data into one 3d array:

```
mydata.ndim
#3
```

where the first dimension (axis) runs over the files, the second over rows, the third over columns:

```
mydata.shape
#(number of files, number of rows in each file, number of columns in each file)
```

So, you can access the first file by

```
mydata[0,...]   # equivalent to: mydata[0,:,:]
```

or specific parts of all files:

```
mydata[0,34,:]    #the 35th row of the first file by
mydata[:,34,:]    #the 35th row in all files
mydata[:,34,1]    #the second value in the 34th row in all files
```

**To write to file:**
Say you want to write a new file with just the 35th row from all files:

```
np.savetxt(os.join(path,'outfile.txt'), mydata[:,34,:])
```

Comment: Hey, sorry about the delayed response. I tried using the code provided by askewchan, but it gave an error like "could not convert string to float). This is because the first the first 34 rows contain strings, so I tried altering it to "...[np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=34)...". Now I get this error instead: "File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "C(python directory)\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 783, in loadtxt fh.next StopIteration" Not sure what this means. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: @Jayden It could mean your file is not sufficiently long... Also, try using `skip_header=34` instead of `skiprows=34`.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I had a file in there which wasn't 34 rows long, so it got stuck. The export code worked like a charm as well, thanks. However, now something else has me stuck. I pretty much directly copied the line of code which worked for the first set of data (I have 3 sets), only changing the path, and imported it again, but for some reason it gave me a 1D array instead of 2D (each file only has 1 column). The result is something like "array([array([data]), array([data]), ... array([data])], dtype = object".

Comment: When I use the data.ndim function it returns 1, and when I use the data.shape function it returns "(*number of files*, )". Somehow it's treating the output like a 1D array with a bunch of array entries. I tried restarting the console and have rerun the code from scratch several times, always with the same result. Any ideas? Thanks for your continued assistance.

Comment: That means that each of your files is not the same shape, and a numpy array must be uniform (each row the same length, etc).  So you have an array of arrays, which you have to access like a list of lists.  So, the first file, 34th row is at: `mydata[0][34]` not `mydata[0,34]`.

Comment: Excellent. Working like a charm now. Thanks! Just 1 more quick question if you don't mind, since you have been so awesome so far :). Most of the data files I use have a string at the end of the file to signify the end. How can I ignore just this last line in a file? I have seen other people ask this question, but can't seem to get an easy answer. Cheers!

Comment: If it's always the same string at the beginning of the line, use `comments=str`. If it's always one line at the end, you could use `skip_footer=1`.  There are other options [at the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to read from a file and write to a file you can use open().

For a better solution, you can use [linecache](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html)